# Create one-page website, scrollable vertical and horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, zooming

I'd like to create a one-page website where you can click a button and navigate to a different part of the website by automatically moving to it. This movement could be to the left, right, up or down.

This is an example of how the full, zoomed out page would look like: 
[image: page example]

The idea is that only one of these pages should be visible at a time in the browser. So when you're on the "main page", you only see that one, and not what's to the left, right, up or bottom from it. You should be able to move to these around it by clicking links on the page.

Now I have no idea how to start this. Do I make one giant html page, like the image, and do the zoom and movement to an other page with some JavaScript library?

Or will I have to make this completely in the canvas object? If so, any useful libraries I could use?

Thanks in advance,
Ruben

Comment: I did something like this before. It's depend the content you your site. If it not so big content, you can do this in one div that "moves" within the "wrapper" element with `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Heres a tutorial that does a similar thing to what you need http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need, thank you very much!